# YouTube Subscription List API V3 [ unable to check subscribed user is still subscribed or not to my channel ]

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using subscription/insert API to make user subscribe to my channel.

```
Responsedata{

    kind:   "youtube#subscription"
    etag:   "zNS9wkFH3YQT16N-f5BI8-bRK48"
    id: "nSXLoI9bATpwVV8r7RGYlTiW3C3jrJ95s3ND0_KKkD8"
    snippet{    
        publishedAt:    "2021-11-29T06:22:06.367041Z"
        title:  "Jagadeesh Mekala"
        description:    ""
        resourceId{ 
            kind:   "youtube#channel"
            channelId:  "UCY4_uFTS5CsiLiNFTPagzqg"
        }
        channelId   "UC3KouvQ9tJwntWCWuDbBM9g"
        thumbnails  {…}
    }
    status  200
}
```

From the above response I am using `snippet.channelId` to check whether the user is subscribed or not.

POST:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet,contentDetails&key=apiKEY&forChannelId=UC3KouvQ9tJwntWCWuDbBM9g&mine=true
```

RESPONSE:

```json
{

    "kind": "youtube#SubscriptionListResponse",
    "etag": "qk1Tfs_Oukrn0Zd-vTvE13i0vIY",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 0,
        "resultsPerPage": 5
    },
    "items": []
}
```

If that first response's Response Channel id is subscribed it should return an array with details,
but I got an empty array.

Are there any other methods to achieve this thing?

Comment: Have you tried recovering all your subscribers with OAuth with only `part=snippet,contentDetails` and `mySubscribers=true` ?

Comment: yeah, but it will return the list of people who had you tube channels